# dig returns wrong record type

Tags: dns, cname, dig, a-records

This seems like I am either missing something obvious, or it would have been asked before. When I query `dig` using the `-t` parameter to specify a DNS record type, the result seems to contain an answer even if the record returned is a different record type. Here is an example:

```
$ dig -t A -q polestar.databaseguy.com.

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> -t A polestar.databaseguy.com.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33130
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;polestar.databaseguy.com.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
polestar.databaseguy.com. 3600  IN      CNAME   databaseguy.ddns.net.
databaseguy.ddns.net.   60      IN      A       173.19.127.251

;; Query time: 30 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.10.1#53(10.0.10.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec 10 14:41:50 STD 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103
```

The `CNAME` and `A` records listed in the `ANSWER SECTION` are correct. However, the `CNAME` is for `polestar.databaseguy.com.` and the `A` is for `databaseguy.ddns.net.`. There is no `A` record for`polestar.databaseguy.com.`, which is what I queried for, so I expected there to be no results.

I am pretty confident this is the correct behavior, but I don't understand it and didn't see any explanation in the `man dig` pages. I also could not find other discussions online, either on this site or elsewhere. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Downvoters, please explain your votes. From this question, I learned that I was thinking about this as an nslookup/dig issue when it was really a protocol issue, and hence that I should have looked to DNS documentation instead of dig documentation. That's hardly nothing if it helps someone else traverse that knowledge path more quickly in the future.

I do understand the impulse to downvote, but in my OP I even mentioned that I thought the behavior was correct, so it's not like I was a million miles in left field on this, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, that decreases the amount of exchanges needed, and is specific of the `CNAME` record.

It is covered by the core documents on DNS: [RFC1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), section 3.6.2

See this:

> CNAME RRs cause special action in DNS software.  When a name server
> fails to find a desired RR in the resource set associated with the
> domain name, it checks to see if the resource set consists of a CNAME
> record with a matching class.  If so, the name server includes the
> CNAME record in the response and restarts the query at the domain name
> specified in the data field of the CNAME record.  The one exception to
> this rule is that queries which match the CNAME type are not
> restarted.

With the clear example that completely matches your case:

> For example, suppose a name server was processing a query with for
> USC-ISIC.ARPA, asking for type A information, and had the following
> resource records:
>
> ```
> USC-ISIC.ARPA   IN      CNAME   C.ISI.EDU
>
> C.ISI.EDU       IN      A       10.0.0.52
> ```
>
> Both of these RRs would be returned in the response to the type A
> query, while a type CNAME or * query should return just the CNAME.

See section 5.2.2 for other points.
Sections 6.2.7 and 6.2.8 also gives examples.

It also depends if you query a recursive or an authoritative nameserver.

`databaseguy.com` has for nameservers:

```
pdns01.domaincontrol.com.
pdns02.domaincontrol.com.
```

If you query one of them:

```
$ dig A polestar.databaseguy.com. @pdns01.domaincontrol.com.

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> A polestar.databaseguy.com. @pdns01.domaincontrol.com.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64115
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: e45ebc418c94c90a
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;polestar.databaseguy.com. IN A

;; QUERY SIZE: 65

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64115
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;polestar.databaseguy.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
polestar.databaseguy.com. 1h IN CNAME databaseguy.ddns.net.
```

You get only the CNAME value because this authoritative nameserver knows only that, and is not authoritative for `ddns.net`.

But if you ask any **recursive** nameserver it does the job of recursing and giving you the "full" reply:

```
$ for ns in 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9 80.80.80.80 ; do dig A polestar.databaseguy.com. @$ns +noall +ans ; done

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> A polestar.databaseguy.com. @1.1.1.1 +noall +ans
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> A polestar.databaseguy.com. @8.8.8.8 +noall +ans
;; global options: +cmd
polestar.databaseguy.com. 59m59s IN CNAME databaseguy.ddns.net.
databaseguy.ddns.net.   59s IN A 173.19.127.251

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> A polestar.databaseguy.com. @9.9.9.9 +noall +ans
;; global options: +cmd
polestar.databaseguy.com. 1h IN CNAME databaseguy.ddns.net.
databaseguy.ddns.net.   1m IN A 173.19.127.251

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> A polestar.databaseguy.com. @80.80.80.80 +noall +ans
;; global options: +cmd
polestar.databaseguy.com. 1h IN CNAME databaseguy.ddns.net.
databaseguy.ddns.net.   1m IN A 173.19.127.251
```

(`1.1.1.1` did not reply to my query but this is irrelevant here for this question)

So about "There is no A record forpolestar.databaseguy.com., which is what I queried for, so I expected there to be no results." this is halfway wrong because that name has a CNAME which means another canonical name and this canonical name has an `A` record so at the end of the day it is exactly as if the starting name had an `A` record. Any application locally asking the OS for the IP address of that host will get the A record, as the OS will take care of the full recursive resolution and "dereferencing" the CNAME.

Comment: Thank you for a fantastic answer! I did not know where to look for this documentation, and this not only resolves the issue for me but also gives me the idea (obvious in hindsight) that I should consider the protocol documentation, and not just the application documentation, when facing a question like this one.